Are questions involving improbable human conditions on topic?
I can think of a range of questions that relate hypothetical assumptions that are not true, and probably will never be true. But the question builds on that assumption to ask a meaningful psychological question.
Here's one we had on the site:

If time travel were possible, would travelling back in time result in memory loss?

Here's a few others that I can imagine:

Would it be more adaptive for humans to have four arms?
How would social relationships change if asexual reproduction was possible?
What would be the effect on mother-child bonding if babies could be produced in plastic tubes?

Meta Question

Are such questions on topic for this site? Why? Why not?
If on topic, what are the requirements of such questions?
Should they have a specific tag?



To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ____ happened?”


Sounds to me like it falls under one of the canonical examples from the site help.

These sort of questions should be held to a higher standard of initial research than other questions on the site. For your specific examples:

If the person is asking about time-travel then they should should familiarity with how physicists and computer scientists think about time travel. 
If they are asking about the adaptiveness of four-arms then their question has to show a basic understanding evolutionary theory, and what effects having two arms has had on our brain/culture. 
If they are ask about social relationships and asexual reproduction then their question should show a knowledge of existing literature on the role of sex, reproduction, and child rearing or relationships. It should also be sensitive to existing non-reproductive, and asexual (in the sexual orientation, not reproduction, sense) romantic relationships.
If they ask about test-tube babies and mother-child bonding then they should show knowledge of existing bonding research (for instance, postpartum depression), and a grasp of actual studies of artificial reproduction (whether it is host-mothers, adapted children, or studies in non-human animals).

Without these higher standards (we've already dropped our standards too low on most questions), the questions should be quickly closed as not serious, subjective, and lack-of-initial research. They should also be downvoted as bad questions.

My first instinct was to say that such questions should not be allowed on the site. They are not serious questions or they are impossible to answer accurately. And we often talk about the impact of seeing certain types of questions on new users of the site, and whether such questions will attract the right kinds of users.
However, the other part of me finds it quite interesting to ponder the implications of changing one aspect of reality but holding psychological theory broadly constant. 
Clearly, there are rules for answering such questions, and there are better and worse answers. So, my preference would be to give such questions a chance, and just reward well written answers that are well grounded in psychological theory.
